# Build or test errors when trying to build a node.js app with typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, tsc

I'm building a node.js app with typescript that will only run from the command line.

I have a the following in my package.json:

```
{
  "type": "module",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "npx jest",
    "start": "node dist/index.js",
    "build": "npx tsc --build tsconfig.json"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "jest": "^26.6.1",
    "ts-jest": "^26.4.2",
    "typescript": "^4.0.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.15",
    "@types/node": "^14.14.2"
  }
}
```

The following in my tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "include": ["src"],
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "module": "esnext",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "rootDir": "./src",
        "strict": true,
        "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "paths": {
            "*": ["node_modules/*"]
        },
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
    }
}
```

And the following directory structure:

[image: dirs]

All of my tests fire and pass fine, so node/typescript have no problem reading them and processing them:

[image: tests pass]

And typescript will build the files fine. But when I try to fire the built versions, I get an error `Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module`:

[image: import error]

Even though the file's relative path is definitely correct.

[image: relative path]

I've tried a bunch of different permutations of different package.json `type` values, tsconfig.json `module` and `target` values, but I can't seem to figure out how to get the build to work correctly.

Any ideas?

Comment: try remove `"type": "module",` in your `package.json` file, or remove `paths ` setting in your `tsconfig.json` file.

Comment: @hoangdv I did both. Jest would fail when I removed either. I did eventual get it working by importing with the `.js` extension at the end of the module file names, but I'm waiting till I get home to post the answer because it's on my other computer.